# DELETE then INSERT in one query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oledb, sql-server-ce

Is there a way I can delete the old record, then insert a new one? I have an Excel spreadsheet and I'm using OLEDB, then pass it to SQL Server CE command to insert into `.sdf` database file.

I want to delete the old record *or update the old record (much better)* then insert a new one.

I have data in spreadsheet `EmployeeLeaveHistory` containing columns `Emp_Num` and `Emp_Name`

```
Emp_Num | Emp_Name |
--------+----------+
12345   | anna     |
12345   | anna     |
23451   | jonalyn  |
```

By using oledb it will get the record

```
        int EmployeeNum;
        string EmployeeName;
        string constr = "";
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Excel/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);

        if (ext.Trim() == ".xls")
        {
            constr = "Povider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel.8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }
        else if (ext.Trim() == ".xlsx")
        {
            constr = " Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }

        string query = "SELECT * FROM [EmployeeLeaveHistory$]";

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (OleDbDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr2.Read())
                    {
                        EmployeeNum = Convert.ToInt32(dr2["Emp_Num"]);
                        EmployeeName = Convert.ToString(dr2["Emp_Name"]);

                        SaveLeave(EmployeeNum, EmployeeName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I have a private void SaveLeave who will catch the record from oledb then insert it to my `.sdf` file.

```
private void SaveLeave(Int32 EmployeeNum, string EmployeeName)
{
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
       string check = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEELEAVEHISTORY WHERE Id=@@IDENTITY";
       string update = "UPDATE EMPLOYEELEAVEHISTORY SET EmployeeName=@EmployeeName WHERE EmployeeNum=@EmployeeNum;";
       string insert = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELEAVEHISTORY(EmployeeNum, EmployeeName) VALUES (@EmployeeNum, @EmployeeName);";

        using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(constring))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(check, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeNum", EmployeeNum);

                using (SqlCeDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    read.Read();

                    int count = read.GetInt32(0);

                    if (count > 0)
                    {

                        using (SqlCeCommand upt = new SqlCeCommand(update))
                        {
                            upt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeNum", EmployeeNum);
                            upt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoOfDays", NoOfDays);
                            upt.Connection = con;
                            upt.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {                            using (SqlCeCommand inst = new SqlCeCommand(insert))
                        {
                            inst.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeNum", EmployeeNum);
                            inst.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", EmployeeName);
                            inst.Connection = con;
                            inst.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }          
        }
    }
```

If I use Delete statement, the last row of Excel record which is `23451|jonalyn|` is the only one that's being inserted to the sdf. Right now I'm using update statement but the problem is when I use update statement, the record is not updating but it duplicate the record, also if I add another record in my excel like this:

```
Emp_Num | Emp_Name |
--------+----------+
12345   | anna     |
12345   | anna     |
23451   | jonalyn  |
12      | jade     |
```

And use insert query to my `.sdf`, the record in my `.sdf` becomes like this:

```
EmployeeNum | EmployeeName |
------------+--------------+
12345       | anna         |
12345       | anna         |
23451       | jonalyn      |
12345       | anna         |
12345       | anna         |
23451       | jonalyn      |
12          | jade         |
```

Can anyone help me? THANK YOU

Comment: i tried to put semicolon in one statement but it gives me error

Comment: what was the error? kinda helps us see what's going on...

Comment: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 34,Token in error = INSERT ]

Comment: you may want to use a transaction

Comment: if i use  using (SqlCeCommand inst = new SqlCeCommand("DELETE FROM EMPLOYEELEAVEHISTORY;INSERT INTO EMPLOYEELEAVEHISTORY(EmployeeNum, EmployeeName) VALUES (@EmployeeNum, @EmployeeName); ", con))
it gives me that error

Comment: I came of an idea using if else statement, if the record is in the database it will update/delete, then insert

Comment: `DELETE FROM EMPLOYEELEAVEHISTORY` You want to delete **all** rows?

Comment: the problem i'm facing is if i get the record from excel using oledb then throw it to private void saveleave which contains parameters and sqlce statements. when i try to update, the record does not updating instead it inserts the record again. so instead of 3 (three) records it becomes 6(six) records. then if there's already a record in my sdf and i add another one to excel with the same Emp_num but different Emp_name, it updates the record which have the same Emp_num.

Comment: example.
i created record from excel which have
 Emp_num / Emp_name
1               / jay
2             / june
1            / jay
then throw it to saveleave, it insert the first three record
but when i add another one in excel spreadsheet, the record in sdf becomes like this

Emp_Num/ Emp_Name
1               / jay
2             / june
1            / jay
1               / jay
2             / june
1            / jay
5           / mark

Comment: @mjwills yes. because in my excel the old record is still there so that is not a problem if i delete all rows, it just increase the primary key

Answer (score 0):

I try different way to do update statement but every record that have the same EmployeeNum is being updated by the last record fetched by OLEDBcommand. the best way for me is to delete record and insert new one (take note the only problem here is if you remove the old record in excel file it cannot be retrieve unless you save the old record in another excel file).

here's the code for DELETE statement then INSERT.

```
            string query2 = "SELECT * FROM [EmployeeLeaveHistory$]";
            using (OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(query2, conn))
            {
              using (OleDbDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(constring))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        string del = "DELETE FROM EMPLOYEELEAVEHISTORY";
                        using (SqlCeCommand delete = new SqlCeCommand(del))
                        {
                            delete.Connection = con;
                            delete.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }


                        using (SqlCeBulkCopy copy = new SqlCeBulkCopy(con))
                        {
                            copy.DestinationTableName = "EMPLOYEELEAVEHISTORY";

                            copy.ColumnMappings.Add("Emp_Num", "EmployeeNum");
                            copy.ColumnMappings.Add("Emp_Name", "EmployeeName");


                            copy.WriteToServer(dr2);


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```